# Need help understanding direction formula

Tags: javascript, math

```
Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90) + 3) % 4;
```

Hello,

This formula is supposed to take coordinates in an x y plane and return an integer from 0-3 that describes the location of the coordinates.

> 0:top, 1:right, 2:bottom, 3:left.

I understand that math.atan2 gets the angle and then the 180/pi converts it to degrees. The author said that he added 180 to get rid of negative numbers, but I don't see why there would be any negative numbers. Then he adds 3 and uses the modulo operator 4 (because 4 quadrants).

Does anyone understand why he adds 180 and then 3?
What's even more confusing is that If I plugin an angle like pi/2 (which should return 0:top) I get 2.

Comment: What coordinate system are you using? Where are angle 0 and angle 90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula is intended for coordinate system MM_TEXT, where zero angle is right direction and Pi/2 angle is down direction.

Step-by-step:

`* (180 / Math.PI)` translates angle range to -180..180 degrees
`+ 180` translates angle range to 0..360 degrees, so right direction (old zero) becomes 180
`/ 90` makes 0..4 range, so right direction (old zero) becomes 2
`+ 3`  shifts range to 3..7, so right direction (old zero) becomes 5
`% 4` gets modulus, so right direction (old zero) becomes 1

Comment: The MDN docs say that angles in the lower half plane are negative and angles in the top half are positive. So how can down direction be positive pi/2?

Comment: Oh I just realized. The y value is calculated from offset.top which means it increases as you go down. It's not Math.atan2 that is upside down. It's the coordinate system set up beforehand.

Comment: It depends on coordinate system orientation. Picture on that page shows system with counterclockwise angle direction, which is used in mathematics usually (OX to right, OY to top). Default coordinate system in computer graphics uses coordinate origin in the top left corner, clockwise angle direction with , axis OX to right, OY to down.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, an arctangent can return a negative angle. As mentioned in the [MDN docs on `atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2):

> returns a numeric value between -π and π

For instance, for point **(-1, -1)**, **atan(y, x)** returns **-(3/4)π = -135°**

```js
console.log(Math.atan2(-1, -1));
```

So by adding 180, the formula will translate the range [-180, +180] to [0, 360].

The next step in the formula is to divide by 90, and round that result. So now the above range is reduced to values **{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}**. But since we added 180° those numbers are shifted:

```
Original angle range | After adding 180 | After dividing
---------------------+------------------+---------------
   -180...-135       |    0... 45       |      0
   -135... -45       |   45...135       |      1
    -45...  45       |  135...225       |      2
     45... 135       |  225...315       |      3
    135... 180       |  315...360       |      4
```

Three things remain to be done at this stage:

- Values outside the range {0, 1, 2, 3} (like the 4) need to be mapped inside of it. This is what the modulo operator does (`%`)
- The numbering needs to shift, as you want the top side to get number 0 (After the division by 90, the top side angles get number 3).
- The numbering direction needs to be opposite, as you want right to be numbered 1, while currently the numbering is anti-clockwise.

You can achieve this by subtracting the intermediate result from 7 (instead  of adding 3 to it) and then take the modulo:

```
Original angle range | After adding 180 | After dividing | Subtract from 7 | Modulo 4
---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------
   -180...-135       |    0... 45       |      0         |     7           |    3
   -135... -45       |   45...135       |      1         |     6           |    2
    -45...  45       |  135...225       |      2         |     5           |    1
     45... 135       |  225...315       |      3         |     4           |    0
    135... 180       |  315...360       |      4         |     3           |    3
```

Expression to use in JavaScript:

```
(7 - Math.round(((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90)) % 4
```

#### Other numberings

There are in fact 8 ways to number sections consecutively from 0 to 3: there are 4 ways to choose which section will be 0, and 2 directions: clockwise or anti-clockwise.

Here are the modifications to bring at the start of the formula for each of those 8 possibilities:

```
(7 -  ...
(6 -  ...
(5 -  ...
(4 -  ...
(0 +  ...
(1 +  ...
(2 +  ...
(3 +  ...
```

Just pick the one that gives the desired results.